# What are the configurations required for Apache (HTTPD) for enabling directory/file writing and file uploading?

Tags: php, linux, web-applications, centos

Hie,
I have installed a new httpd server and loaded my web application on it which is designed to upload files on the server. Also it creates new directories and files inside the web directory of the application. But i am unable to use these features because it gives me a permission denied error. I searched onto the web and got the clue that i require to enable ftp login through my PHP script. I changed the ownership and permissions but it is still not working. Can please someone explain the configuration required in simple steps to enable these features. I am using CentOs-6. It will be highly appreciated. Sorry for the miss formed question.

Configurations I tried out:

> Create a Linux user and group named webuser. Give it permissions of
>   the directory of my web applications. Install Vsftpd and allow webuser
>   to login. Set webuser FTP root directory same as my Web Application
>   directory (i.e /var/www/mysite)
>   My httpd user is apache.

Comment: forget ftp... if your script is going to create files/dirs the http server has the rights to create files/dir in this directory... look up the username of the httpd process and chown your directory to it... (and please dont use chmod 777 !!)

Comment: How to give http server the permission to create files?
even chmod 777 doesn't worked.. :(

Comment: `chown <username> directory`. mostlikly `chown apache /var/www/whatever/`

Comment: Already did.. Please check the edits of my question.

Comment: this is the way to do it... show the php code, and confirm that your apache user (or httpd user) is indead called apache.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything right. The only problem was CentOS SELinux. It was not allowing apache to write files into the web directory. 
Using the command "setenforce 0" , i closed it down and everything started working.
Later, I added an exception into my SELinux policies to fix issues.